# Swiftui - text in sheet corrupted by opening a second sheet under some conditions

Tags: swiftui

On iOS 16.4 with XCode 15.1, I'm seeing a SwiftUI behavior for this set of conditions:

1. I have a ContentView that opens a first `.sheet()` which opens a second `.sheet()`.
2. The ContentView has a `List` with a `Section` that has a header `View`.
3. The first `.sheet()` has a `Form` or a `List`

In this set of conditions opening the second sheet changes the font of text in the first sheet to a smaller font.

Any suggestions on how to workaround this behavior?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListHeaderText : View {
    public let text : String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
    }
}

struct FirstSheetContentView: View {
    @State var showSecondSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form { // the bug doesnt happen without this form
                Button("Open Second Sheet - this text is smaller after opening the second sheet") {
                    showSecondSheet = true
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondSheet, content: {
                    SecondSheetContentView()
                })
                Text("This text turns gray after opening the second sheet")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondSheetContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is the second sheet")
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var item: Item?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    Button("Tap to open first sheet") {
                        item = Item()
                    }
                } header: {
                    ListHeaderText(text: "This header causes the bug")
                }
                .overlay(
                    EmptyView()
                        .sheet(item: $item) { item in
                            FirstSheetContentView()
                        }
                        .textCase(.none) // without this everything in FirstSheetContentView is capitalized
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try moving both `.sheet(...)` outside their `NavigationStack`.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 17 and earlier you can't currently use more than one presentation modifier like `sheet`, `popover` etc. Hopefully will be fixed by iOS 18.

https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5597349300666368

But you might be able to workaround your specific bug by reading the state in body. `body` is only called for states that are set if they have previously been read. This normally always happens but can be a problem in simple test `View`'s like yours, just fix like this:

```
 NavigationStack { [showSecondSheet] in
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but the other answer fixed this issue.